# Sourcing Vim settings inside .vimrc

Tags: vim

I've been trying to order my `.vimrc` a bit -
divide everything into different files and source everything in it:

```
source ~/.vim/settings/general.vim
source ~/.vim/settings/functions.vim
source ~/.vim/settings/bindings.vim
source ~/.vim/plugins/autocorrect/plugin/autocorrect.vim
source ~/.vim/settings/playground.vim
```

The `general.vim` contains all the settings of Vim (e.g. `set nocompatible`).
So far, only `binding.vim` and `autocorrect.vim` seem to work.
The first two files have to be included in the `.vimrc` for them to work.

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: What if you source these files manually?

Comment: Hmm, good question. and the answer is no - I tried sourcing my general.vim file and it won't budge. I then tried to comment the binding.vim inside the .vimrc and source it manually and it worked perfecftly.

Comment: I think you need to give some more information. What is written in these files? Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Each file contains something else - The general.vim contains general settings (e.g. set number), functions.vim contains custom functions, binding.vim - well, key bindings etc...I don't think - I know it doesn't work, simply because nothing of the settings seems to work (no highlight when searching, no numbers, no syntax etc..)

Comment: Can you show the smallest possible file that doesn't apply settings when `source`'d?

Comment: Yes, I played around and found that only the first statement seems to be accepted. meaning, if I have set number<cr> set hlsearch, only the number works. When I removed the comments, vim threw me an error488: trailing spaces, between the "set" and the "number".

Comment: If you solved your problem then you probably should answer question yourself and accept the answer.

Comment: I didn't solve my problem though - the trailing space makes no sense. It's exactly the same line, copy-pasted in the other file. Only when pasted in the other file does it throw me an error. And why should it throw an error over a white space that's supposed to be there (between two words)?

Comment: Edit your question and add the smallest possible file that vim complains when source it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.
It eventually WAS an issue of trailing spaces, only I failed to recognize it with the text editor.
When removed, it worked perfectly.